# Getting errors in registering the COM DLL

Tags: dll, dllregistration

when i was trying to register my own com dll it is giving me error  as

"The module ClassLibrary was loaded but entry point dllregister server  was not found.

Comment: That sounds like an informative error message - which bit didn't you understand?

Comment: @RogerRowland hi, i didn't understand what does that error mean?

Comment: It means that your dll was loaded ok but there is no exported function called `DllRegisterServer`. Are you perhaps trying to register a .NET COM assembly using `regsvr32`? If so, try using `regasm` instead.